# Connect to remote SQLBase database using sqltalk

Tags: database, sqlbase, sqltalk

I modified my sql.ini file to connect to a remote server hosting an SQLBase db, so I added the following line:

```
[win32client.ws32]

serverpath=serverName,IP_ADDRESS,PORT_NUMBER/*
```

But I get the following error when executing the command `set server serverName;` in the SQLTalk console:

```
Error: 09024 GCI SEA Session ended abnormally
```

```js
[dbntsrv]
dbname=ISLAND
servername=server1
cache=2000
sortcache=2000
readonly=0
oracleouterjoin=0
logfileprealloc=0
partitions=0
optimizerlevel=2
ansijoinsyntax=0
dbdir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Unify\Team Developer 6.0
tempdir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Unify\Team Developer 6.0

[dbntsrv.dll]
comdll=sqlws32

[win32client]
clientname=MY_CLIENT_NAME
clientruntimedir="C:\Program Files (x86)\Unify\Team Developer 6.0" 

[win32client.dll]
; order of win32client dll's is important when connecting to multiple databases. 
; sqlws32 should always be the last and sqlodb32 be 2nd last. 
; comdll=sqlora32 
; comdll=sqlsyb32 
; comdll=sqlodb32 
comdll=sqlws32 

[win32client.ws32]
serverpath=serverName,IP_ADDRESS,PORT_NUMBER/*

[oragtwy]
remotedbname=ora10g,@tns:ora10db
longbuffer=32767
fetchrow=20
substitute=SYSSQL.,
[sybgtwy]
remotedbname=test, hostname, master, 0
[odbcrtr]
odbctrace=off
odbctracefile=sql.log
longbuffer=250000
```

The server seems to use an SQLBase 11.5 database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show the whole client side sql.ini . ( If you are running SQLTalk from the client ).
If you are running SQLTalk form the server , please send the server side Sql.ini.
And make sure you only have ***one*** sql.ini on the client .

Comment: Check my last edit, I'm running SQLTalk from my client computer, the IP_ADRESS is that of the server, the port number after the comma in the client sql.ini is the one I found in my server sql.ini file.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that I need to include a userName/password to connect to the remote server, because I have to do it when I use remote desktop connection to connect to the server hosting the database I wanna access to.

Comment: I also would like to pinpoint that in my IP_ADDRESS I also included the port number, so my the address looks like (X.Y.Z.W:PORT_NUMBER), can this be the origin of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Client SQL.ini looks standard and ok.

Have you tried the File Server *Name*, rather than File Server IP e.g.

```
serverpath=SQLBaseServerName,FileServerName,2155/*
```

Although the Error code 09024 gives:
Reason: Either the remote computer is powered off, the cable link is broken, the session SEND or CHAIN SEND has timed out, or the SEND or CHAIN SEND was cancelled, or a HANG UP timed out waiting for a SEND to complete.

Remedy: Check the remote end for status and check the cable.  For a SEND or CHAIN SEND, or RECEIVE or RECEIVE ANY, re-establish the session.

Usually if all is well Network wise ( are you sure ?) , then everything Gupta ( including TeamDeveloper)  on the client has to be shutdown and re-started.

If SQLBase is running as a Service,  stop and restart the Service on the Server .
If possible, see if you can 'Set Server' on the (File) Server version of SQLTalk, to check the SB Server is listening at all.